# Finding efficient Solution in Python

Tags: python, performance

I'm working in a project and I have a function:

```
def myMin(L):
    current = L[0]
    for x in L:
        if x < current:
            current == x
    return current
```

It is very readable but not so efficient. How can I make it more efficient? I'd rather not use `min`.

Comment: Belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/. Also, did you mean `current = x` ?

Comment: How is it not efficient, aside from the `current = x` problem, your code is O(n), which is as best as it can get. If you're looking to do insertions, deletions, and repetitive `min` findings, you might want to look up a few data structures, which provide a O(1) amortized time.

Comment: This doesn't seem inefficient. It can't use fewer steps (well, you could have one less comparison), and it's hard to see how each step could be much faster. What are you trying to do that needs to be faster? Using the built-in would probably be the most efficient way. Why can't you use it?

Comment: What is wrong with `min`?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Most likely homework

Comment: @Haidro I can't imagine that efficiency is that critical for homework. But I can't imagine that anything that isn't homework couldn't use `min`. In other words, I can't imagine why this question is being asked. It needs some more explanation.

Comment: @Zipp I did a quik analysis, and I don't think you can get faster than your code. Unless the inbuilt `min()` function is not optimised, your code is not much slower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not inefficient, just incorrect. You have a `==` where you need a `=`.

```
current = x
```

Comment: Apologies to all those people who pointed this out in the comments already, I didn't see them.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that, but, i would like to find another solution, more eficient if it could be possible

Comment: @Zipp, why do you think a more efficient solution would be possible? And why can't you use the more efficient solution that Python provides already?

Answer (score 0):

I did not use `min` and this will only be a little bit slower than `min`.

```
def myMin(L):
    L = [i * -1 for i in L]
    return max(L)*-1
```

Seriously though, `min` is probably efficient enough.

edit:
Probably the most efficient you are going to get *without* min, is surprisingly the OPs code, but `sorted(L)[0]` is close as well. However, I'd assume that the interpretter is doing some optimisation on the OPs code, or possibly just converting it directly to `min()`.

This shows the run time of 4 approaches, the OPs, recursive function of Sergio, `min` and `sorted(L)[0]`:

```
import timeit
import random


t = timeit.Timer(
stmt="min([random.randint(0,100) for r in xrange(100)])",
setup="import random")
print "min(L) \t\t-", t.repeat(number=10000)

t = timeit.Timer(
stmt="sorted([random.randint(0,100) for r in xrange(100)])[0]",
setup="import random")
print "sorted(L)[0] \t-", t.repeat(number=10000)

t = timeit.Timer(
stmt="myMin([random.randint(0,100) for r in xrange(100)])",
setup="""import random
def myMin(L):
    if len(L)==1:
        return L[0]
    else:
        half=len(L)/2
        if myMin(L[half:])<=myMin(L[:half]):
            return myMin(L[half:])
        else:
            return myMin(L[:half])"""
)

print "Sergio \t\t-", t.repeat(number=10000)

t = timeit.Timer(
stmt="myMin([random.randint(0,100) for r in xrange(100)])",
setup="""import random
def myMin(L):
    current = L[0]
    for x in L:
        if x < current:
            current == x
    return current
"""
)
print "OP \t\t-", t.repeat(number=10000)
```

And the results:

```
>>> min(L)          - [1.3573479652404785, 1.3553318977355957, 1.3567471504211426]
>>> sorted(L)[0]    - [1.4576461315155029, 1.4571821689605713, 1.4570169448852539]
>>> Sergio          - [8.265916109085083, 8.2540609836578369, 8.2737438678741455]
>>> OP              - [1.4068629741668701, 1.4091939926147461, 1.4070329666137695]
```

Comment: Also, max(L)[-1] will do the same thing ;)